# after update targetd and rtslib clients could not connect anymore

Tags: iscsi

update of targetcli and python-rtslib changed attribute optimal_sector to 512 and removed attribute fabric_max_sectors from the config.

target is running, listening on port 3260 but clients (Windows) can't connect.

Event log:

```
"Initiator failed to connect to the target. Target IP address and TCP Port number are given in dump data" Source: iscsiprt, eventID 1 error
```

and

```
"iSCSI discovery via SendTargets failed with error code 0xefff0003 to target portal *ip address 0003260 Root\ISCSIPRT\0000_0." MSiSCSI eventID 113 warning
```

targetd doesn't work either:

```
targetd.service - targetd storage array API daemon
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/targetd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-08-28 17:10:58 CEST; 7s ago
  Process: 39839 ExecStart=/usr/bin/targetd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 39839 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 28 17:10:58 server targetd[39839]: File "/usr/bin/targetd", line 24, in <module>
Aug 28 17:10:58 server targetd[39839]: sys.exit(main())
Aug 28 17:10:58 server targetd[39839]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/targetd/main.py", line 209, in main
Aug 28 17:10:58 server targetd[39839]: load_config(default_config_path)
Aug 28 17:10:58 server targetd[39839]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/targetd/main.py", line 170, in load_config
Aug 28 17:10:58 server targetd[39839]: config[key] = value
Aug 28 17:10:58 server targetd[39839]: TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
Aug 28 17:10:58 server systemd[1]: targetd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 28 17:10:58 server systemd[1]: Unit targetd.service entered failed state.
Aug 28 17:10:58 server systemd[1]: targetd.service failed.
```

yum downgrade doesn't work.
SELinux is disabled.

I'm not familiar with iscsi configuration at all. What is the difference between target and targetd? What key is mention by targetd?

Thank you.

centos7.2

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it turned out to be the network manager who messed up the network bond. It was not disabled and was started by the update process. Stopping the networkmanager and recreating the network bond solved the problem.